# How to add right cards to basic mtg deck?

Tags: python, arraylist, percentage

I am making a python program, just for fun, that will create a basic **Magic: the Gathering** deck.
 The main test right now is if it can make a legal mtg deck that would be fine for beginners.

```
'''a mtg deck designer'''
from collections import Counter
import mtgsdk.card as card

colors = ['black']
#colors = input("What are your colors?").split(', ')
ncolors = len(colors)
ncards = 60
#ncards = int(input("how many cards?"))
mytype = 'Vampire'
#mytype = input('what creature type should the deck be based on?')

def myrange(l):
    '''create an assignable array with l pieces'''
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i != l:
        result.append(i)
        i += 1
    return result

def add(grp, queryresult):
    '''add queryresult[0] to grp'''
    try:
        grp += [queryresult[0]]
    except IndexError:
        '''help!'''

def figure_out_basic_land(clr):
    '''figure out the basic land name of a given color'''
    if clr.lower() == 'colorless':
        return 'Waste'
    if clr.lower() == 'white':
        return 'Plains'
    if clr.lower() == 'blue':
        return 'Island'
    if clr.lower() == 'black':
        return 'Swamp'
    if clr.lower() == 'red':
        return 'Mountain'
    if clr.lower() == 'green':
        return 'Forest'
    return 0

def d1():
    '''first portion of debugging message'''
    print('getting cards', end='...')

def d2():
    '''second portion of debugging message'''
    print('done.')

def construct():
    '''the actual deck-constructing function'''
    #define groups
    basiclands = []
    lowcostcreatures = []
    highcostcreatures = []
    lowcostspells = []
    highcostspells = []
    #assign cards to groups
    for i in colors:
        d1()
        add(basiclands, card.Card.where(types='land').where(supertypes='Basic').where(name=figure_out_basic_land(i)).all())
        d2()
        d1()
        add(lowcostcreatures, card.Card.where(types='creature').where(subtypes=mytype).where(colors=i).where(cmc='1').all())
        add(lowcostcreatures, card.Card.where(types='creature').where(subtypes=mytype).where(colors=i).where(cmc='2').all())
        d2()
        d1()
        add(lowcostspells, card.Card.where(types='instant').where(text=mytype).where(colors=i).where(cmc='1').all())
        add(lowcostspells, card.Card.where(types='sorcery').where(text=mytype).where(colors=i).where(cmc='2').all())
        d2()
        d1()
        add(highcostcreatures, card.Card.where(types='creature').where(subtypes=mytype).where(colors=i).where(cmc='3').where(rarity='rare').all())
        add(highcostcreatures, card.Card.where(types='creature').where(subtypes=mytype).where(colors=i).where(cmc='4').where(rarity='rare').all())
        d2()
        d1()
        add(highcostspells, card.Card.where(types='instant').where(subtypes=mytype).where(colors=i).where(cmc='3').where(rarity='rare').all())
        add(highcostspells, card.Card.where(types='sorcery').where(subtypes=mytype).where(colors=i).where(cmc='4').where(rarity='rare').all())
        d2()
        print()
    #put results into card suggestion pool
    cards = [lowcostcreatures,highcostcreatures,lowcostspells,highcostspells,basiclands]
    #define deck
    deck = []

    #figure out how to get the cards into the deck in sets of 4, with almost correct numbers of each group (30% lowcost,30% highcost,40% land)

    if len(deck) > (ncards):
        while en(deck) > (ncards):
            del deck[-1]
    if len(deck) != ncards:
        print('warning: card num = {0}'.format(len(deck)))
    return deck
```

**The Question:** So far, the `construct` function returns `[]`, because nothing was ever added to it. I'm wondering how to add sets of 3 or 4 (plus 40% basic lands) of a card to `deck` so that it is an array of `ncards` `Card` instances, following the percentages specified below. **Something to remember!** Sometimes there won't be enough cards in a group, and unused cards from other groups must be added to remain 60 cards. Also, the number of cards in the deck may vary, which is why I use percentages in my description of the problem.

Specifications:

1. In the future, the program will use machine learning, but I'm not at that point yet, so I'm just trying to get 15% low-cost creatures, 15% high-cost creatures, 15% low-cost noncreature spells, 15% high-cost noncreature spells, 40% basic lands.
2. Of course, feel free to comment on my percentages, I'm not exactly a pro mtg player, and would love some free advice / helpful criticism!
3. Lastly, if you see any other problems with the code, don't keep quiet! I would love all the help I can get!

Comment: What's your question? If you're looking for a review, and the code works, and is complete, it should be on Code Review, not here.

Comment: So far, the `construct` function returns an empty array, because nothing has ever been added to `deck`. I am asking how to add cards to `deck` so that there are 15% low-cost creatures, 15% high-cost creatures, etc. and hopefully in sets of 3 or 4 of each card

Comment: I just realized that I didn't even state the question!  Just edited it. Thanks @Carcigenicate!